# what's the matter with the free function?

Tags: c, pointers

```
/*
 * delete the first mode whose num match number in the list 
 */
void delete(listnode *list, int num)
{
  listnode *item, *tmp, *prev;
  item = list;

  while (item->next != NULL) {
    if (item->next->num == num) {
      tmp = item->next;
      item->next = item->next->next;
    } else {
      item = item->next;
    }
  }
  /*free(tmp);*/
}
```

so, if I comment free, it works well, else, it will just shot me a core dump, what should I do with the node which tmp point to?(note: assume we have a header, and the parameter list is a pointer to it)

Comment: If `num` occures multiple times in your list you cut each of such/its nodes but only would free the last.

Comment: @alk thanks, I've add a break statement in while. and I've initial tmp to NULL, but it still get a segmentation fault :(

Comment: "*it still get a segmentation fault*" probably because the nodes had not been properly initialised, eg. the next pointer not been initialised to `NULL`.

Comment: And do not edit the original code after comments and answer had been given, this could make them un-understandable. I undid your last edit therefore.

Comment: @gansteed post the code doing the ***allocation*** too

Answer (score 3):

There are several paths of execution which would lead to calling `free` on an uninitialized variable. initialize `tmp` to `NULL`.

Comment: I've initial tmp to NULL, but it still get a segmentation fault :(